# Rails Rspec error - Undefined local variable or method for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_3:0...>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm going through the 11th chapter of Michael Hartl's railstutorial and have run into some rspec errors.

[image: rspec error]

I'm not really sure what the error message means by .

Just in case, here's my spec code.

```
  let(:follower) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  let(:followed) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
  let(:relationship) {follower.relationships.build(followed_id: followed_id)}

  subject {relationship}

  it {should be_valid}

  describe "accessible attributes" do
    it "should not allow access to follower_id" do
      expect do
        Relationship.new(follower_id: follower_id)
      end.to raise_error(ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error)
    end
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line:

> let(:relationship) {follower.relationships.build(followed_id:
>   followed_id)}

To

```
let(:relationship) {follower.relationships.build(followed_id: followed.id)}
```